# Spell checker solution in java

Tags: java, nlp

I need to implement a spell checker in java , let me give you an example for a string lets say "sch aproblm iseasili solved" my output is "such a problem is easily solved".The maximum length of the string to correct is 64.As you can see my string can have spaces inserted in the wrong places or not at all and even misspelled words.I need a little help in finding a efficient algorithm of coming up with the corrected string. I am currently trying to delete all spaces in my string and inserting spaces in every possible position , so lets say for the word (it apply to a sentence as well) "hot" i generate the next possible strings to afterwords be corrected word by word using levenshtein distance : h o t ; h ot; ho t; hot. As you can see i have generated 2^(string.length() -1) possible strings. So for a string with a length of 64 it will generate 2^63 possible strings, which is damn high, and afterwords i need to process them one by one and select the best one by a different set of parameters such as : - total editing distance (must take the smallest one)
-if i have more strings with same editing distance i have to choose the one with the fewer number of words
-if i have more strings with the same number of words i need to choose the one with the total maximum frequency the words have( i have a dictionary of the most frequent 8000 words along with their frequency )
-and finally if there are more strings with the same total frequency i have to take the smallest lexicographic one.

So basically i generate all possible strings (inserting spaces in all possible positions into the original string) and then one by one i calculate their total editing distance, nr of words ,etc. and then choose the best one, and output the corrected string. I want to know if there is a easier(in terms of efficiency) way of doing this , like not having to generate all possible combinations of strings etc.

EDIT:So i thought that i should take another approach on this one.Here is what i have in mind: I take the first letter from my string , and extract from the dictionary all the words that begin with that letter.After that i process all of them and extract from my string all possible first words. I will remain at my previous example , for the word "hot" by generating all possible combinations i got 4 results , but with my new algorithm i obtain only 2 "hot" , and "ho" , so it's already an improvement.Though i need a little bit of help in creating a recursive or PD algorithm for doing this . I need a way to store all possible strings for the first word , then for all of those all possible strings for the second word and so on and finally to concatenate all possibilities and add them into an array or something. There will still be a lot of combinations for large strings but not as many as having to do ALL of them. Can someone help me with a pseudocode or something , as this is not my strong suit.

EDIT2: here is the code where i generate all the possible first word from my string http://pastebin.com/d5AtZcth .I need to somehow implement this to do the same for the rest and combine for each first word with each second word and so on , and store all these concatenated into an array or something.

Comment: sounds like homework, what have you tried?

Comment: i already said , read again. "sounds like homework" and what if it is ? what if it's not ? did i ask for someone to solve the problem for me ? i gave you my ideea and asked for directions.

Answer (score 3):

A few tips for you:

1. try correcting just small parts of the string, not everything at once.
2. 90% of erros (IIRC) have 1 edit distance from the source.
3. you can use a phonetic index to match words against words that sound alike.
4. you can assume most typos are QWERTY errors (j=>k, h=>g), and try to check them first.

A few more ideas can be found in this nice article:

http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Comment: thank you for the tips Dvir , as i see other people got the wrong ideea, I managed to insert spaces inside the string by checking the first letter and creating all possible words within a LD of 2 , and reduces my outputs.I implemented the filter to select the best possible string. My only problem now is that this works withing the time frame i want for strings with a length of 10-15 characters , and i need to find a way to split the string if it is larger into 2 or more strings, but i need to know where to split so i don't take letters from the next word or how do i proceed if i do.

Comment: i already looked at that article and a dozen more about compound splitting , lcs , soundex but i have a different approach , though i did find things i could use. Maybe i should've mentioned that.

Comment: there's a reason why no speller works like that. Having written a couple, I can tell you that you have to limit the length of what you're trying to fix to avoid these issues, and avoid generating random insetions and deletions naively, because it will not scale. you need to think statistics - what makes the user do a typo, how can you best fix it, etc.